# importar pytest dentro de un archivo

Tags: python

he intentado instalar pytest de la siguiente manera en la terminal:
python -m venv venv
ls
env/Scripts/Activate. (utilizando PowerShell)
pip install pytest
pip show pytest
pytest test_main.py

otra manera es:
busco el intérprete de Python correcto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pylance: Python Path no lo encuentro en la configuración